# Regular expressions help

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in php that checks to make sure the string passed in is one of three things, however I am having a hard time (I really struggle with regex).

I need to make sure that my received parameter contains one of these three things, and nothing else:

1. "|" and that's it just a single pipe  OR
2. "" and that's it just an empty string OR
3. "|1|534|3453|23|213|2|"  A long string that uses pipes as a delimiter for a series of numbers

Thank you for your help (this is continually a problem for me, think I need to buy a book exclusively on regex)

Comment: Might I suggest [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126) (AKA the Owl Book)

Comment: There are two things that will help you read regular expressions. This tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and this actionscript site to try out your regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/^(?:\|(?:\d+\|)*)?$/', $input);
```

Comment: Character for character, exactly the same as my answer. Too slow.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc What are the odds of that?

Comment: We should both buy lottery tickets.

Comment: It'd be more maintainable if it were split into 3 checks, but this'll do it.

Comment: @Jeff Three checks? What do you mean?

Comment: +1. Of course, this assumes that the string (if it's not empty) must start and end with `|` (that is, `123|`, `456|` and `78|90` are not valid).  I believe that's correct, but the question wasn't very clear on that point, so it's a good idea to make the assumption explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to split it into three separate checks:

1. The string is just a single pipe (`strcmp($str,"|") == 0`)
2. The string is empty (`strlen($str) == 0`).
3. The string matches the regex `/^[0-9\|]+$/`

Don't make it harder than it needs to be by trying to cram all of those checks into one regular expression. Your code will be more easily understood, and future maintainers of your code will thank you.

**Edit:** Just to display what I'm talking about, here's some sample code:

```
if( strcmp($str,"|") == 0 ||
    strlen($str) == 0     ||
    preg_match('^[0-9\|]+$', $str) {
  ...
}
```

vs

```
if( preg_match('/^(?:\|(?:\d+\|)*)?$/', $str ) {
  ...
}
```

At a glance, which one executes the `...` if `$str` is empty?

Comment: I agree.  Separate it into 3 Regex, and it will be much more maintainable than either of the other current answers.

Comment: You don't even need three regular expressions. The first two checks are trivial uses of `strlen()` and `strcmp()`. I've edited my answer to display these checks.

Comment: That's true, you really only need the regex to test the 3rd condition he listed.  Just goes to prove the old joke: A programmer has a problem.  "I know," he says, "I'll use a regular expression!" Now he has two problems.

Answer (score 0):

(^(\|)([0-9\|]{0,})(\|)$)|(^(\|)$)|()

use above regex and if no mathches your string is not valid, othervise its valid, and try to check of empty if str_len($string) > 0 then check regex